# Warning: GNU Extension

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran, cran, fortran95

When I submit my package to CRAN, it does not pass the automatic incoming checks with a following warning:

```
* checking whether package 'EpiILM' can be installed ... WARNING
  Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: GNU Extension: Different type kinds at (1)
```

and corresponding log file says

```
  Epimcmc.f95:440.25:

        psi= min(1.0,exp(ratio))
                     1
 Warning: GNU Extension: Different type kinds at (1)
```

When I tested my package using  R CMD CHECK and R CMD CHECK --as-cran, both result no warnings or notes. I am using an R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch" on my MacOS and codes are written in Fortran 95.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is too short to diagnose exactly, but it can be probably inferred safely what the not-shown part of the code is.

Your `ratio` is of different kind than default one, probably `double precision.

But `1.0` is the default kind (aka. single precision).

Mixing different kinds in `min()` is not allowed in Fortran, but you do this in:

```
  min(1.0,exp(ratio))
```

To fix the problem, use literals of the same kind as `ratio` is. So if it is a `double precision`, you can use:

```
  min(1.0d0, exp(ratio))
```

and if it is some  `real(rk)` you can use

```
  min(1.0_rk, exp(ratio))
```

The `real(.., kind=rk)` function can also be used.

---

The warning says that the GNU Fortran compiler recognizes it is not allowed in Fortran, but allows it as a non-standard extension. Whether using this extension is allowed by the CRAN coding standards is a different question. Probably no, if it got rejected.

Comment: Thanks. Both 'ratio' and 'psi' are double precision. Will change 1.0 to 1.0d0 and see how that goes.